# Get referenced functions within stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to get a list of referenced function names used inside a specific stored procedure.

I used this query to achieve most of that:

```
select 
    ROUTINE_DEFINITION 
from 
    sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities('[mac].[pr_custom_test_load]', 'OBJECT') sed
inner join
    SYS.OBJECTS so ON so.object_id = sed.REFERENCED_ID AND so.type = 'FN' AND sed.referenced_schema_name = 'mac'
inner join
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES isr ON isr.ROUTINE_NAME=SED.referenced_entity_name AND ROUTINE_TYPE = 'FUNCTION';
```

The problem in some scenarios I am facing is, there are some tables created within the stored procedure. So if the procedure is not executed then the above statement fails stating that rest of the referenced objects were not created .

Is there any  other approach to get the referenced functions within the stored procedure?

Comment: Could you restore question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53923146/filter-those-data-from-table-where-there-is-a-gap-in-sequence? I wanted to post an answer to that interseting puzzle :)

Comment: @LukaszSzozda done i tried out unpivot but than had no clue how to proceed further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK finally i accomplished with an below query :

```
select ROUTINE_DEFINITION FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies AS sed  
INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o ON sed.referencing_id = o.object_id AND sed.referenced_schema_name = 'mac'  
 inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES isr ON isr.ROUTINE_NAME=SED.referenced_entity_name AND ROUTINE_TYPE = 'FUNCTION'
WHERE referencing_id = OBJECT_ID('[mac].[pr_custom_test_load]');
```

> Using **sys.sql_expression_dependencies** you don't need the referenced tables to be created which are referenced in the procedure definition. Whereas in the case of  **sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities** the tables referenced within the procedure definition must exits.