# Filter those data from table where there is a gap in sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

I want to set the doprocess flag to 0 if the below data is empty between any of the targets mentioned

Example:

```
create table TestSAMP (
  id int identity(1,1),
  modelid navrchar(max),
  target1 nvarchar(max),
  target2 nvarchar(max),
  target3 nvarchar(max),
  target4 nvarchar(max),
  doprcoess  int default(1)
)

--VALID SET DOPROCESS FLAG TO 1
INSERT INTO TestSAMP(modelid,target1,target2,target3,target4) 
VALUES('1','T1','T2','T3','T4')

--NOTVALID SET DOPROCESS FLAG TO 0 DUE TO THE DATA IS MISSING IN SEQUENCE 
INSERT INTO TestSAMP(modelid,target1,target2,target3,target4)
VALUES('2','TR','','T3','T4')

--VALID SET DOPROCESS FLAG TO 1 As if data is present
-- it should be present insequence in below t1 t2 as they arfe in sequence
INSERT INTO TestSAMP(modelid,target1,target2,target3,target4)
VALUES('3','T1','T2','','')

--NOTVALID SET DOPROCESS FLAG TO 0 DUE TO THE DATA IS MISSING IN SEQUENCE 
--where T4 data is provided and not in T3
INSERT INTO TestSAMP(modelid,target1,target2,target3,target4) 
VALUES('4','T1','T2','','T4')
```

> I have got lot of solution where people try out to find the sequential
>   number but here the case is nvarchar

Comment: What about using SQL Server Stored Procedure and ISNULL function, you pass all your data as parameters to the procedure, then you do your CHECKING inside.

If the sequence is not as expected, then set DOPROCESS =0

Then make INSERTION. Done :)

Comment: what do you think?

Comment: was thinking about some subquery or unpivot thing   as there is an already procedure created withing it have to set an validation flow . Lot of restriction around this is an some part of pseudo i displayed here

Comment: VALUES('T1','T2','T3','T4') -- is valid
VALUES('T1','T2','T3',' ') -- is valid
VALUES('T1','T2',' ',' ')
VALUES('T1',' ',' ',' ') -- is valid

???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could treat gaps and islands as string i.e. 'IGGI', squash it, and search for 'IGI' pattern:

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN squashed LIKE '%IGI%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS new_doprocess
FROM TestSAMP t
CROSS APPLY(SELECT STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN t = '' THEN 'G' ELSE 'I'END, '') r
             FROM (VALUES (1,id, target1), (2,id, target2),
                          (3,id, target3), (4,id, target4)) sub(rn, id, t)) s
CROSS APPLY (SELECT replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(s.r,'G','<>')
   ,'><',''),'<>','G'),'I','<>'),'><',''),'<>','I')) AS sub(squashed)
ORDER BY t.id;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3c1ab10fd445527777144201a287170d)**

Example:

```
  id  | target1  | target2  | target3  | target4  |  r    | squashed  | doprocess 
 -----|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------|-----------|----------- 
   1  | T1       | T2       | T3       | T4       | IIII  | I         |         1 
   2  | T1       |          | T3       | T4       | IGII  | IGI       |         0 
   3  | T1       | T2       |          |          | IIGG  | IG        |         1 
   4  | T1       | T2       |          | T4       | IIGI  | IGI       |         0 
   5  |          |          |          | T4       | GGGI  | GI        |         1 
   6  |          |          |          |          | GGGG  | G         |         1
```

Comment: More info on solving the gaps and islands problem in SQL https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way should be a Boolean expression checking if a predecessor is empty when a successor is not.

```
UPDATE testsamp
       SET doprocess = 0
       WHERE target2 <> ''
             AND target1 = ''
              OR target3 <> ''
                 AND target2 = ''
               OR target4 <> ''
                   AND target3 = '';
```

You might want to extend it for example if it's also invalid, when all targets are empty. I don't know if you want that.

Comment: i was looking for other than this solution as i have some 15 columns like that so i do not want to make a 15  data scans on table for each column

Comment: @Stickybit It looks likeyou are missing operator for last `AND target3 ''`. Anyway it won't work for `GGGI` [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4407e9599de44e030ac4c80ac3ca4ac0). Of course we could discuss what is the author intention for such case

Comment: @LukaszSzozda: Thanks I corrected it. It indeed works different than your solution as I understood the demand like that.